# How can i Instantiate objects in a group?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        objectPool = new ObjectPool(objectToInstantiate, objectsToInstantiate);

        float randX = 0f;
        float randZ = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++)
        {
            if (random == true)
            {
                //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
                randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
                randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
            }
            else
            {

            }

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            var randScaleX = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.x, RandScaleMax.x);
            var randScaleY = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.y, RandScaleMax.y);
            var randScaleZ = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.z, RandScaleMax.z);
            var randVector3 = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            clonedObject = objectPool.GetInstance();

            if (randomScale == true)
                clonedObject.transform.localScale = randVector3;//new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            if (parent)
                clonedObject.transform.parent = this.transform;

            clonedObject.tag = "ClonedObject";

            clonedObject.transform.position = new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ);
        }

        createdObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objname);

        UpdateList(false, "ClonedObject");
    }
```

This will Instantiate objects in random places over the terrain area.

I want in the else when it's not random to place the objects in a group with two main parameters/variables, one to set the space between the objects the second to set how to make them in lines for example if in objectsToInstantiate there are 20 objects and i set a variable to 4 and another variable to 10 then the objects will be in lines of 4 that is 5 lines and the space between the objects will be 10 from every side.

If i have 55 objects and i set to make it in lines of 4 then there will be 14 lines of 4 the last line will be with 3 objects.

For example a paint of 4 objects in a row and 5 lines in space of 10:

[image: Example]

And in case there are for example 23 objects then it will look like that:

[image: Example1]

Comment: If the images describes what you are shooting for better than the code then this is not random. Why are you even using the`Random.Range` for this if they should be equally spaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't try but this should work.

```
int columns = 4;
int space = 10;//set these variables from your parameters

Vector2 CalcPosition(int index) // call this func for all your objects
{
    float posX = (index%columns)*space;
    float posY = (index/columns)*space;
    return new Vector2(posX, posY);
}
```